# Terraform Multiple State Files Best Practice Examples

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to build out our AWS environments using Terraform but am hitting some issues scaling.  I have a repository of just modules that I want to use repeatedly when building my environments and a second repository just to handle the actual implementations of those modules.

I am aware of HashiCorp's Github page that has an example but there, each environment is one state file.  I want to split environments out but then have multiple state files within each environment.  When the state files get big, applying small updates takes way too long.

Every example I've seen where multiple state files are used, the Terraform files are extremely un-DRY and not ideal.

I would prefer to be able to have different variable values between environments but have the same configuration.

Has anyone ever done anything like this?  Am I missing something?  I'm a bit frustrated because every Terraform example is never at scale and it makes it hard for n00b such as myself to start down the right path.  Any help or suggestions is very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/environments.html?

Comment: Thank you.  I must have not read the docs since they added this feature in 0.9

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The idea of *environment* unfortunately tends to mean different things to different people and organizations.

To some, it's simply creating multiple copies of some infrastructure -- possibly only temporary, or possibly long-lived -- to allow for testing and experimentation in one without affecting another (probably *production*) environment.

For others, it's a first-class construct in a deployment architecture, with the environment serving as a container into which other applications and infrastructure are deployed. In this case, there are often multiple separate Terraform configurations that each have a set of resources in each environment, sharing data to create a larger system from smaller parts.

Terraform has [a feature called *State Environments*](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/environments.html) that serves the first of these use-cases by allowing multiple named states to exist concurrently for a given configuration, and allowing the user to switch between them using the `terraform env` commands to focus change operations on a particular state.

The *State Environments* feature *alone* is not sufficient for the second use-case, since it only deals with multiple states in a single configuration. However, it can be used in conjunction with other Terraform features, making use of the `${terraform.env}` interpolation value to deal with differences, to allow multiple state environments within a single configuration to interact with a corresponding set of state environments within another configuration.

---

One "at scale" approach (relatively-speaking) is described in my series of articles [Terraform Environment+Application Pattern](http://apparently.me.uk/terraform-environment-application-pattern/), which describes a generalization of a successful deployment architecture with many separate applications deployed together to form an environment.

In that pattern, the environments *themselves* (which serve as the "container" for applications, as described above) are each created with a *separate* Terraform configuration, allowing each to differ in the details of how it is configured, but they each expose data in a standard way to allow multiple applications -- each using the *State Environments* feature -- to be deployed once for each environment using the *same* configuration.

This compromise leads to some duplication between the environment configurations -- which can be mitgated by using [Terraform modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html) to share patterns between them -- but these then serve as a foundation to allow other configurations to be generalized and deployed multiple times *without* such duplication.

Comment: Since Terraform 0.11.something, `terraform env` has been renamed to `terraform workspace`